# JSON data into variable

Tags: json, https, json-server

**EDIT**: I solved that error, however, it only seems to print out just one instance. How can I make it put all the entries into that variable?

I'm a little bit too new to this, but I'm trying. Sorry if the question sounds stupid.
I've configured a JSON server and it works just fine. I can pull out the data successfully, however, the data I receive I'd like to go into a variable so that I can use it later on in another function. For this purpose, I created the variable dategraph. However, it doesn't seem to work good. It doesn't seem to read it outside the $each loop. Any ideas what could it be?
I tried using console.log() in the $each loop and it works fine, however, it won't work outside of it.

```
function solicitare() {
  adresa = "http://localhost:4000/listaexamene?callback=?";
  $.getJSON(adresa, function (raspuns) {
    $.each(raspuns, function (indice, examen) {
      continutDeAfisat = "<div><i>Subiect: " + examen.examId + "</i>, Student: " + examen.studentId + "</div>";
      $(continutDeAfisat).appendTo("#datenoi");

      var dategraph = {};
      dategraph.examId = examen.examId;
      dategraph.studentId = examen.studentId;
    });
    console.log(dategraph);
    stringNou = JSON.stringify(dategraph);
    console.log(stringNou);
  });
}
```

The error I receive is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the variable in an inner scope. So the outer scopes don't know what that variable is. Try:

```
function solicitare() {
  const dategraph = {}; // <---
  const adresa = "http://localhost:4000/listaexamene?callback=?";
  $.getJSON(adresa, function (raspuns) {
    $.each(raspuns, function (indice, examen) {
      const continutDeAfisat = "<div><i>Subiect: " + examen.examId + "</i>, Student: " + examen.studentId + "</div>";
      $(continutDeAfisat).appendTo("#datenoi");

      dategraph.examId = examen.examId;
      dategraph.studentId = examen.studentId;
    });
    console.log(dategraph);
    const stringNou = JSON.stringify(dategraph);
    console.log(stringNou);
  });
}
```

*Avoid using `var` and use `let` instead.*

Simply doing `myNewVariable = {};` will work, but javascript will not be very happy with you. When declaring new variables always use `let` or `const`.

Use `const` when you *wont* re-assign a value to a variable.

Use `let` when you *will* re-assign a value to a variable in the future.

---

**Local Arrow Functions**. Instead of doing:

```
$.getJSON(adresa, function (raspuns) {
  $.each(raspuns, function (indice, examen) {
```

You can do:

```
$.getJSON(adresa, (raspuns) => {
  $.each(raspuns, (indice, examen) => {
```

The only time you generally don't want to do this, is when you are working with the `this` keyword in javascript.

---

**Unused local variables** i.e. `indice` in your case, since you aren't using it. People usually do `_` to indicate that it's an unused variable. So you can use either do `_indice` or `_`, or even easier, just do `(, examen)`.

---

**String interpolation**. As you can see, its pretty annoying to do `"<div><i>Subject:" + examen.examId + "...."`. Instead of `""` make the string with ``` `` ```. Then you can do string interpolation with variables like this `${examen.examId}`.

---

This is what I'd do.

```
function solicitare() {
  const dategraph = {};
  const adresa = "http://localhost:4000/listaexamene?callback=?";
  $.getJSON(adresa, (raspuns) => {
    $.each(raspuns, (_, examen) => {
      const continutDeAfisat = `<div><i>Subiect: ${examen.examId}</i>, Student: ${examen.studentId}</div>`;
      $(continutDeAfisat).appendTo("#datenoi");

      dategraph.examId = examen.examId;
      dategraph.studentId = examen.studentId;
    });
    console.log(dategraph);
    const stringNou = JSON.stringify(dategraph);
    console.log(stringNou);
  });
}
```

---

If you write your javascript in VS code, I can also recommend to install an extension called `prettier` which will help format your code and make it more readable.

---

**New question**: *How can I make it that it saves all the answers from the loop and not just one?*

Try this:

First, make `dategraph` an array. Then we push each result object into the array. So something like this:

```
function solicitare() {
  const dategraph = []; // <--- make array
  const adresa = "http://localhost:4000/listaexamene?callback=?";
  $.getJSON(adresa, (raspuns) => {
    $.each(raspuns, (_, examen) => {
      const continutDeAfisat = `<div><i>Subiect: ${examen.examId}</i>, Student: ${examen.studentId}</div>`;
      $(continutDeAfisat).appendTo("#datenoi");
      
      // push result into array
      dategraph.push({
        examId: examen.examId,
        studentId: examen.studentId,
      });
    });
    console.log(dategraph);
    const stringNou = JSON.stringify(dategraph);
    console.log(stringNou);
  });

  console.log("Final dategraph:", JSON.stringify(dategraph, null, 2));
}
```

Comment: Wow! We need more people like you sir! That solved it! Thank you kindly!

Comment: I'll accept your answer once the minimum time of acceptance passes on.

Comment: @Stef2nn np. See updated answer. Don't forget to set `const` for variables you wont re-assign a new value to. `let` for variables you will re-assign. Simply not writing anything will still work, because javascript will assume it's a new declaration, but its not very good practise :) gl

Comment: I haven't really been working much in javascript but this surely helps! Thank you again!

Comment: I can add some more explanation in the answer on stuff I see in your code so you'll hopefully learn a new thing or two :)

Comment: That'd be highly appreciated! I'm already loving this community

Comment: One more question. How can I make it that it saves all the answers from the loop and not just one?

Comment: @Stef2nn Please see bottom of answer for what you are asking for 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244911/discussion-between-stef2nn-and-joel).